# How to use the ‘Shape’ of qml to draw creator a complicated control

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am trying to make a beautiful tab bar just like this:
[image]
Could someone teach me how to draw such complex controls in qml development
[image]

I am a beginner and have no idea to deal with it

I hope some one could teach me

Comment: Easiest way of doing nice graphics stuff like this is using images as a background for your tabs.

Comment: I have made a version with picture. But my boss aks me to make a version with 'Shape'! Oh! T-T

Comment: Tell him, that it makes no sense ;)

Comment: The only advantage I can think of to using a Shape here would be that you could adjust the size of the tabs to fit the text, but there are ways to do that with images too. I would take a look at [BorderImage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-borderimage.html).

Comment: My boss said using shape will have better performance than image. Is it true?

Comment: hmm, offtopic but it is worth thinking about changing your place of work -)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it yourself with Path and PathArc. Not going to be easy, but it is doable.

[PathArc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-patharc.html#details).

Answer (score 0):

Using `Shapes` you can create probably whatever you want. Actually I don't think you're going to get any performance gains compared to the image but anyway...

I've created some simple example, all the values are hardcoded for simplification:

[image]

The code

```js
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Shapes

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 400
    title: "Tab example"

    Row {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        spacing: -35
        Repeater
        {
            id: panel
            property var active: null
            model: 3
            delegate: Item {
                z: 1
                id: btn
                property bool active: false
                width: 200
                height: 50
                Shape {
                    antialiasing: true
                    width: 200
                    height: 50
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    ShapePath {
                        strokeWidth: 3
                        strokeColor: "#999"
                        fillGradient: LinearGradient {
                            x1: 100;
                            y1: 0;
                            x2: 100;
                            y2: 50;
                            GradientStop { position: 0; color: btn.active ? "#aaa" : "#ccc" }
                            GradientStop { position: 0.5; color: btn.active ? "#efefef" : "#fefefe" }
                            GradientStop { position: 1; color: btn.active ? "#bbb" : "#ddd" }
                        }
                        startX: 0;
                        startY: 50
                        PathQuad { x: 20; y: 25; controlX: 20; controlY: 40 }
                        PathQuad { x: 40; y: 0; controlX: 20; controlY: 3 }
                        PathLine { x: 160; y: 0 }
                        PathQuad { x: 180; y: 25; controlX: 180; controlY: 3 }
                        PathQuad { x: 200; y: 50; controlX: 180; controlY: 40 }
                        PathLine { x: 0; y: 50 }
                    }

                    Text {
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        text: "Click me"
                        font.pointSize: 16
                        color: btn.active ? "black" : "grey"
                    }

                    MouseArea {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        anchors.leftMargin: 40
                        anchors.rightMargin: 40
                        onClicked: {
                            btn.active = true;
                            if(panel.active != null && panel.active != btn)
                            {
                                panel.active.active = false;
                                panel.active.z = 1;
                            }

                            panel.active = btn;
                            btn.z = 2;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you will get some ugly antialiasing, add these lines into main.cpp:

```cpp
QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setSamples(8);
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);
```

or

```js
layer.enabled: true
layer.samples: 8
```

to the `Item` instead