# In qml, how to make the "shadow" of "Shape" more beautiful?

Tags: qt, qml

I make a tab bar demo of this:

[image: Tambor Choice Card]

And here is my code:

```
    Item {
        id: myItem
        property bool active: false
        property int customWidth: 200

        width: 200 + 115 + 115
        height: 72
        x: 100
        y: 20

        containmentMask: myShape

        Shape {
            id: myShape
            y: 8
            antialiasing: true
            width: 200 + 115 + 115
            height: 64
            anchors.centerIn: parent

            ShapePath {
                strokeWidth: 0

                fillColor: "white"
                startX: 0
                startY: 64

                PathArc {
                    x: 30
                    y: 30
                    radiusX: 32
                    radiusY: 32
                    useLargeArc: false
                    direction: PathArc.Counterclockwise
                }

                PathArc {
                    x: 64
                    y: 0
                    radiusX: 32
                    radiusY: 32
                    useLargeArc: false
                    direction: PathArc.Clockwise
                }

                PathLine {
                    x: 115
                    y: 0
                }

                PathLine {
                    x: 115 + myItem.customWidth
                    y: 0
                }

                PathLine {
                    x: 115 + myItem.customWidth + 51
                    y: 0
                }

                PathArc {
                    x: 115 + myItem.customWidth + 51 + 34
                    y: 34
                    radiusX: 32
                    radiusY: 32
                    useLargeArc: false
                    direction: PathArc.Clockwise
                }

                PathArc {
                    x: 115 + myItem.customWidth + 115
                    y: 64
                    radiusX: 32
                    radiusY: 32
                    useLargeArc: false
                    direction: PathArc.Counterclockwise
                }
                PathLine {
                    x: 0
                    y: 64
                }
            }
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.leftMargin: 40
            anchors.rightMargin: 40
            onClicked: {
                console.log("clicked")
            }
        }
    }

    DropShadow {
        source: myItem
        anchors.fill: myItem
        radius: 3
        horizontalOffset: 0
        verticalOffset: 0
        color: ReharkUIColor.brand06
        spread: 0.2
    }
```

But,is still has difference between my code and the design in Shadow.
I have tried different ways,but I can not solve this problem, I can not make my shadow as soft as the design.

[image: The Design]

Comment: As a start you should move your DropShadow into your item. Source should be myShape, I guess.

Comment: Are you going to upvote any of the answers from the previous version of this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76602934/how-to-use-the-shape-of-qml-to-draw-creator-a-complicated-control ?

Comment: All this hazzle just to prevent an easy image solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

So, I fixed your shape, which was really a mess. Now the shape is more generic and simpler to adjust the effect scale on it. you can also change the width of curves.

To add more shadow from the sides, there is a simple solution: 
By using a *blur effect* and *x-scaling* it from the shape center, you can achieve the desired result.

In this example, I used [`MultiEffect`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-effects-multieffect.html), which is a multipurpose component in Qt6 that helps merge multiple effects into a single component.

*If you are using Qt5, use [`FastBlur`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-fastblur.html) instead of drop shadow for better performance.*

You can also set the `colorizationColor` to change the color of the shadow effect beneath the shape.

> **NOTE:** In my opinion, I do not advise using `Shape` as it is not implemented properly and has very poor results compared to other libraries like *qnanopainter* or *pure shader*.

[image: shadow preview image]

```
component MyShape: Shape {
    id: shape

    property real halfHeight: height/2
    property real curveWidth: height/3

    ShapePath {
        strokeWidth: 0
        fillColor: '#fff'
        startX: 0; startY: shape.height
        PathQuad { x: curveWidth; relativeY: -halfHeight; relativeControlX: curveWidth; relativeControlY: 0}
        PathQuad { x: 2 * curveWidth; y: 0; controlX: curveWidth; controlY: 0}
        PathLine { x: shape.width - curveWidth * 2; y: 0 }
        PathQuad { relativeX: curveWidth; relativeY: halfHeight; relativeControlX: curveWidth; controlY: 0}
        PathQuad { relativeX: curveWidth; relativeY: halfHeight; relativeControlX: 0; controlY: shape.height}
        PathLine { x: 0; y: shape.height }
    }
}

MultiEffect {
    source: myshape
    anchors.fill: myshape
    blurEnabled: true
    blurMax: 25
    blur: 1.0
    colorizationColor: '#000'
    colorization: .2

    transform: Scale {
        xScale: 1.05
        origin.x: myshape.width / 2
    }
}

MyShape {
    id: myshape
    width: 200; height: 50
    
    anchors.centerIn: parent
}
```